# Remove parentheses in powershell regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

I cant find a find an answer that is clear to me. I am changing a bunch of image file names in a directory, when I rename them they all get renamed to `image (1).png` `image (2).png` for as many images as I have then I run this in power shell.

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace " ","_" }
```

This finds the space and renames it to `image_(1).png` `image_(2).png` nice and easy, but It becomes a headache trying to replace the parentheses. I am trying to get rid of them to look like this `image_1.png` `image_2.png` but it's gotten really frustrating finding an answer lol.

I wish I could just write.

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "\(*\)","*" }
```

or

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "\([1-10]\)","[1-10]" }
```

or

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "\(\W\)","\W" }
```

I tried them all and you would think that syntax is valid, but nope :( So I am hoping for  a little nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have enough SO Rep to comment on your question so I have to try for an answer. Do you need to escape your backslashes? ie. Replace

```
"\(*\)","" with "\\(*\\)",""
```

Is your issue with the command syntax or the Regex itself? The raw Regex would look something like this:

```
^(?\<Name>.*)\((?<Number>\d*?)\)\.(?<Extension>.*$)
```

and replace with:
${Name}_${Number}.${Extension}

Comment: I need to remove them, having () in file names aren't really flexiable when using in css and stuff. I am not 100% what the issue is, I know some syntax's are valid but make no changes, and them some I tried like @EBGreen's answer give me an error saying cannot rename.

Comment: I just updated my response to correct the formatting. The regex I posted will capture those and strip out the parens replacing them with the initial underscore. So: image (1).png becomes image _1.png

Comment: Okay I am trying it now, thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: Sure. Bear in mind, it's possible you'll have to use double backslashes when using my solution. I don't know if powershell requires you to escape those characters in strings or not, but I'd assume you probably would.

Comment: nice this `Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "\(*\)","" }` removed one side of the parentheses file name looks like this `image_(1.png` almost there but not sure why it didnt remove both?

Comment: If you're trying to use your original command, just put two backslashes everywhere you'd use one. If you're trying to use the regex I supplied, it would be something like: Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "^(?\<Name>.*)\((?<Number>\d*?)\)\.(?<Extension>.*$)", "${Name}_${Number}.${Extension}" } If that doesn't work you might also have to replace any single '\' with '\\'

Comment: ok thats what I am trying now to use // I need to rename the files should take a minuet be right back, thanks again.

Comment: It said this regex is not valid `Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "^(?\<Name>.*)\((?<Number>\d*?)\)\.(
?<Extension>.*$)", "${Name}_${Number}.${Extension}" }` The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName
((?<Number>\d*?)\)\.(?<Extension>.*$) is not valid.

Comment: Got it to work I did this first `Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "\(*\)", "" }` to remove ) then did `Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "\(*\(", "" }` to remove ( ... Thanks again, this was way more difficult than I would have liked..

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name.replace(' ','_') -replace '[()]','' }
```

The string `.replace()` method is much more efficient for single literal character replacement.  Use the -replace operator for more complex operations where you need to specify multiple characters at once.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't comment under the answer but this is a way to getting rid of the "()" and the text inside in one go.

```
Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name -replace "(\(\d+\))",""}
```

The `\(` and `\)` escapes the parentheses making them literal parentheses. The non-escaped parentheses group the captured pattern to be referenced later and may not be needed here for what you are doing.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I did with two lines
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $*.name –replace "(","" }
 Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $*.name –replace ")","" }